# Mongoose query filters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I have a mongoose schema like this:

```
const popupDetails = new mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        default:""
    },
    message:{
        type:String,
        default:""
    },
    redirectPath:{
        type:String,
        default:null
    },
    creditsScored:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },
    isSeen:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    },
    _id:false


})

const popupSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"User",
        index:1
    },
    popupsArray: [popupDetails]

    
})
```

Now I want to filter the popupsArray based on whether isSeen is false or not.  I want to send all the popups from popups array to the client whose isSeen is false and also change isSeen to true on the go. How can I achieve this?

This is how I am filtering it right now:

```
try {
        const reqPopups = await popupSchema.aggregate([
            {
              '$match': {
                'user_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`${user_id}`)
              }
            }, {
              '$unwind': {
                'path': '$popupsArray', 
                'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
              }
            }, {
              '$match': {
                'popupsArray.isSeen': false
              }
            }
          ])
          res.json({user_id,reqPopups})
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.json({error})
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The main problem I am facing is to change isSeen to true.

Comment: Kindly show your attempt to create the filter and we can correct it from there. Preferably with your desire final object output. Kindly include a sample document too if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
await popupSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(`${user_id}`)
        },
        {
          isSeen: false
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      isSeen: true
    }
  }
])
```